# Dict.merge is deprecated, what's the simplest way to merge a Keyword List with a Map?

Tags: elixir

The `Dict` module was soft deprecated starting in Elixir v1.2. We're now at 1.4 and it raises warnings:

> Dict.merge/2 is deprecated, use the Map module for working with maps or the Keyword module for working with keyword lists

Dict.merge used to work like this:

```
iex(1)> animals_keyword_list = [cats: 2, dogs: 1]
[cats: 2, dogs: 1]
iex(2)> animals_map = %{cats: 3, rabbits: 1}
%{cats: 3, rabbits: 1}
iex(3)> Dict.merge(animals_map, animals_keyword_list)
%{cats: 2, dogs: 1, rabbits: 1}
```

What's the best way to handle a simple keyword list -> map merge going forward?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `Map` and `Keyword` implement the `Enumerable` and `Collectable` protocols, so we can use `Enum.into/2`:

```
iex(4)> animals_keyword_list |> Enum.into(animals_map)
%{cats: 2, dogs: 1, rabbits: 1}
```

Note, this solution requires you to be happy that if there are duplicate keys in the keyword list, the last one declared will overrule any previous ones as Maps cannot have duplicate keys. You can see this when you instead do the reverse and merge the Map into the Keyword List, which can support duplicate keys:

```
iex(5)> animals_map |> Enum.into(animals_keyword_list)
[cats: 2, dogs: 1, cats: 3, rabbits: 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Dict.merge/2` you should simply use `Map.merge/2`.

```
map1 = %{name: "bob"}
map2 = %{name: "fred", wife: "wilma"}
Map.merge(map1, map2) # %{name: "fred", wife: "wilma"}
```

The same rule for keyword lists and using `Keyword.merge/2`.

In your example I would use `Map.merge/2` with `Enum.into` for keyword list.

```
Map.merge(animal_map, Enum.into(animal_keyword_list, %{}))
```

or only using `Map` module:

```
Map.merge(animal_map, Map.new(animal_keyword_list))
```

Comment: This would work but is a lot more verbose than simply using Enum.into alone; I would say leaning on Elixir's in-built protocols is the more idiomatic way to go about this.

Comment: I ran a few benchmarks and they come very close in terms of performance, so I would guess the `Enum.into/2` approach would be preferred as it's less verbose and clearer, unless you want the second argument to be a keywordlist AND the output to be a map, then you must take this approach

Answer (score 0):

[Keyword.merge](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#merge/2) is the perfect solution e.g

```
iex> Keyword.merge([a: 1, b: 2], [a: 3, d: 4])
[b: 2, a: 3, d: 4]
```